# R - using set_names in map fails

Tags: r

First let's create an example directory on which this example is ran:

```
c("Level1/Level1A/Level1AA", 
  "Level1/Level1A/Level1AB", 
  "Level1/Level1B/Level1BA", 
  "Level1/Level1B/Level1BB",
  "Level2/Level2A/Level2AA", 
  "Level2/Level2A/Level2AB", 
  "Level2/Level2B/Level2BA", 
  "Level2/Level2B/Level2BB") %>% 
  map(dir.create, recursive = T)
```

What I would like is to get a named nested list which mirrors this folder structure. It obligatory has to be in tidyverse style. I am trying to build it bit by bit. The first part of my code seems to work well:

```
list.dirs(recursive = F) %>% 
  map(list.dirs, recursive = F) %>% 
  set_names(str_split(., "/") %>% 
              map(pluck, 2))
```

The output is the following:

```
$Level1
[1] "./Level1/Level1A" "./Level1/Level1B"

$Level2
[1] "./Level2/Level2A" "./Level2/Level2B"
```

So we can see that the list element names are indeed `Level1` and `Level2`, as expected. In the next step, I want to create the next sublevel of the list. However, my code fails:

```
list.dirs(recursive = F) %>% 
  map(list.dirs, recursive = F) %>% 
  set_names(str_split(., "/") %>% 
              map(pluck, 2)) %>% 
  map_depth(2, list.dirs, recursive = F) %>% 
  map(set_names, str_split(., "/") %>% 
        map_depth(2, pluck, 3))
```

The output is as follows:

```
$Level1
$Level1$`list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)`
[1] "./Level1/Level1A/Level1AA" "./Level1/Level1A/Level1AB"

$Level1$`list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)`
[1] "./Level1/Level1B/Level1BA" "./Level1/Level1B/Level1BB"


$Level2
$Level2$`list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)`
[1] "./Level2/Level2A/Level2AA" "./Level2/Level2A/Level2AB"

$Level2$`list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)`
[1] "./Level2/Level2B/Level2BA" "./Level2/Level2B/Level2BB"
```

So the problem is that, for example, the first sublevel of the first level of the list is now named `list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)` instead of `Level1A`.

I don't understand why this happens.

How is my code supposed to look like?

Please the answer has to be pipe-friendly. Thank you.

**EDIT:** The structure which I desire is the following:

```
list(Level1 = list(Level1A = c("Level1AA", "Level1AB"),
                        Level1B = c("Level1BA", "Level1BB")),
     Level2 = list(Level2A = c("Level2AA", "Level2AB"),
                        Level2B = c("Level2BA", "Level2BB")))
```

Comment: What would you like the output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something along these lines?

```r
library(tidyverse)

list.dirs(recursive = FALSE) |>
  map(\(.x) map(.x, 
                \(.y) list.dirs(path = .y, recursive = FALSE)) |>
        set_names(str_extract(.x, "(?<=/)\\w+(?=$)"))) |>
  map(\(.x) map(.x, 
                \(.y) map(.y, 
                          \(.z) list.dirs(path = .z, recursive = FALSE) |>
                           str_extract("(?<=/)\\w+(?=$)")) |>
              set_names(str_extract(.y, "(?<=/)\\w+(?=$)"))))
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$Level1
#> [[1]]$Level1$Level1A
#> [1] "Level1AA" "Level1AB"
#> 
#> [[1]]$Level1$Level1B
#> [1] "Level1BA" "Level1BB"
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$Level2
#> [[2]]$Level2$Level2A
#> [1] "Level2AA" "Level2AB"
#> 
#> [[2]]$Level2$Level2B
#> [1] "Level2BA" "Level2BB"
```

EDIT
updated for desired output:

```r
list.dirs(recursive = FALSE) |>
  map(\(.x) list.dirs(path = .x, recursive = FALSE) ) |>
  set_names(str_extract(list.dirs(recursive = FALSE), "(?<=/)\\w+(?=$)")) |>
  map(\(.x) map(.x, \(.y) list.dirs(path = .y, recursive = FALSE)|>
                           str_extract("(?<=/)\\w+(?=$)")) |>
        set_names(str_extract(.x, "(?<=/)\\w+(?=$)"))) 
#> $Level1
#> $Level1$Level1A
#> [1] "Level1AA" "Level1AB"
#> 
#> $Level1$Level1B
#> [1] "Level1BA" "Level1BB"
#> 
#> 
#> $Level2
#> $Level2$Level2A
#> [1] "Level2AA" "Level2AB"
#> 
#> $Level2$Level2B
#> [1] "Level2BA" "Level2BB"
```

Comment: Very close to what I need. The output of your answer seems to be `list(list(Level1 = list(Level1A = c("Level1AA", "Level1AB"), Level1B = c("Level1BA", "Level1BB"))), list(Level2 = list(Level2A = c("Level2AA", "Level2AB"), Level2B = c("Level2BA", "Level2BB"))))`, whereas I need `list(Level1 = list(Level1A = c("Level1AA", "Level1AB"), Level1B = c("Level1BA", "Level1BB")), Level2 = list(Level2A = c("Level2AA", "Level2AB"), Level2B = c("Level2BA", "Level2BB")))`. I will edit the question and add the desired structure.

Comment: updated. How does that look?

Comment: That's it, I've accepted your answer!

Comment: Additionaly, many thanks for displaying the use of the \ operator. I haven't encountered it before, it looks very helpful and I will be using it heavily